# Most efficient way to detect Google Voice Search installation on Android device

Tags: search, voice

I wanted to ask,... What would be the most efficient way to detect the [Google Voice Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.voicesearch&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nb29nbGUuYW5kcm9pZC52b2ljZXNlYXJjaCJd) (app id: com.google.android.voicesearch) installation on Android device?
And is there any way of subsequently installing it without taking user to Play Market and back to application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below method

```
private boolean voiceSearchExists() {
    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    final List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
    boolean packageExists = false;
    boolean activityExists = false;
    for(PackageInfo r:packs){
        String pkg = r.applicationInfo.packageName;
        if(pkg != null && pkg.equals("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox")){
            packageExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(packageExists == false)
        return false;

    for(ResolveInfo r:pkgAppsList){ 
        ActivityInfo info = r.activityInfo;
        if(info!=null && info.name!=null && info.name.equals("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.VoiceSearchActivity")){
            activityExists = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return activityExists;
}
```

Comment: You cannot however install apps from google play without opening it.